# SOQL query returning empty list

Tags: soql

I'm trying to query for a custom object.

In the query editor in the Developer console, this query returns 1 row.

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Household_Served__c LIMIT 1000
```

But then when I code it in Apex, the list is empty.

```
List<Household_Served__c> h = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Household_Served__c LIMIT 1000];
System.debug(h.size());
```

Why is the editor returning a row, but in Apex it is not returning anything?

Comment: Where is the Apex being invoked? Is it being run from a test?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are running the query in the Developer Console as the code using the same user?

Comment: It is being run from a test. And yes, that is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you specify the [seealldata=true](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm) attribute (which I don't recommend) then the test will not be able to access live data. You would need to create the custom object record(s) within your test, or inside a [@testsetup](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses) method.

Comment: I'm fairly new to salesforce development and I was trying to avoid this because the object has so many relationships.

Comment: Your test should set-up any data that it needs within it. The `seealldata` attribute would be a workaround, but I personally wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @JoeyThomaschaske More to the point, by depending on SeeAllData, your package won't be easily portable to other organizations (e.g. new Sandboxes, possibly Production, and so on). Make your test data in your unit test so you can avoid complications later. I personally use a class called TestData that creates all the relationships in order, allowing me to re-use the logic across many (or all) of my tests.